# "WheelController" does not contain a definition for "brakeTorque"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been following a tutorial on basic car controls and when I was coding along there was a part where he applied motorTorque and brakeTorque but when I used them, I just got the error that said: "WheelController" does not contain a definition for "brakeTorque" and no accesible method "brakeTorque" accepting a first argument of type "WheelController" could be found.

[image: A picture of the code]

thank you in advance.

I expected it to work just fine but it didn't.

Comment: First of all, please don't provide images of code, paste the actual code into your question. Secondly, I find it very odd that the `WheelController` class you made here has `WheelController` properties inside. Please review the tutorial again but pay special attention to things like spelling etc.

Comment: oh my bad, thanks for the note I don't think I would have seen the wording error and also sorry for not including the code in text.

Comment: yeah those `WheelController` should probably rather be `WheelCollider`

Answer (score 0):

If the tutorial is not using any assets from the assets store ,You are probably using Wheel Controller instead of wheel collider
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WheelCollider.html Replace wheel controller with wheel collider

Can you add a link  to the tutorial you are following if this dosen't solve your issue